# Create View and create index statements are getting generated before create table statements in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: database, oracle, ssms, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to migrate a database from Oracle to MS SQL Server.
When I try to export a database in an sql file from my database in Oracle SQL Developer, Create View statements are getting generated before the create table statements. So, when I run the script on the SQL server, it obviously throws the error view doesn't exist.

How to get "create table..." statement to be generated first in the sql export file?

If there is a way I can choose to only run "Create table.." statements in SQL Server itself, I want to know that as well.

Any solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Removed the sql server tag as this is not a sql server issue. It is about the code generation in Oracle.

Comment: @Sean, Thank you for the guidance (I'm new to posting questions on SO). I have selected SQL Server tag because, if there is a way I can choose to only run "Create table.." statements in SQL Server itself, I want to know that as well. I will update that in question as well so that it will be clear.

Comment: That does seem odd, but I don't see a way to change it. If 'force' is ticked it doesn't really matter - when recreating in Oracle - as the view will just be created as invalid, and recompile when referenced. Presumably the generated DDL will need some modification to run in SQL Server anyway, so they can just be moved manually in the file? Or do two exports, one without the views, the second with just views? Not ideal...

Comment: We can tell when you're trying to escape to SQL Server #Joke

Use the cart feature. Drag your objects to the cart, export the cart. You'll get a series of well-ordered scripts.